# Read a latex file and convert to data frame

Tags: r

I try to read a bib file and convert it into dataframe.

It works properly

```
library(bib2df)

path <- "C:/Users/User/Downloads/test.bib"

df <- bib2df(path)
```

but the column with authors has the first name. Maybe the problem has to do with punctuation. Is there any way to fix it?

```
df$AUTHOR
[[1]]
[1] "Farnaz Behrang and"

[[2]]
[1] "Haicheng Chen and"

[[3]]
[1] "Yiqun T. Chen and"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `bib2df` doesn't like the linebreaks in the author field. It's easy enough to read in the file, change these linebreaks to spaces, save a copy, then read that instead:

```r
library(bib2df)

bib <- readLines("test.bib")
bib <- gsub("and\n\\s+", "and ", paste(bib, collapse = "\n"))
writeLines(bib, "test2.bib")

df <- bib2df("test2.bib")

df$AUTHOR
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Farnaz Behrang"  "Alessandro Orso"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Haicheng Chen" "Wensheng Dou"  "Dong Wang"     "Feng Qin"     
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Yiqun T. Chen"     "Rahul Gopinath"    "Anita Tadakamalla"
#> [4] "Michael D. Ernst"  "Reid Holmes"       "Gordon Fraser"    
#> [7] "Paul Ammann"       "Ren{\\'{e}} Just"
```